# single node akka application with multi-node in mind

Tags: scala, akka

I have a single node akka application that I have to plan the design for.

Can you seamlessly scale to a multi node cluster with fairly simple refactoring or is this something I have to research allot in order to design this to scale in the future?

I don't need multi-node as of yet, but I don't want to design it in such a way where making it multi node will need a re-write of sorts.

Comment: to have it cluster aware "MVP" could be not too complicated,  but while akka single node ensure you can replay a message and you do not lose state when the actor dies and a new gets ccreated... when using remote or cluster, you will be require to use akka-persistence in order to achieve the same.

In akka-persistence you must define actions and state in a certain way, so, I would recommend you to look into it, if you haven't before. I believe that having this, the rest will be more machinery and configuration than other things. 
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence.html